# optimization of for loop apart from enumerate

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to iterate over thousands of elements in a list currently using for loop like,

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,..........]
for i in range(len(lst)): 
    .................
```

is there any optimized way where I can replace the for loop, tried to utilize enumerate but it needs counter and value and isn't helpful for the cause

Please help me on this I'm a beginner in python.

Comment: Hi Phot, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add more content? What is happening in the loop? What do the list elements do? (Particularly, is the list always just ascending numbers from 1 to N?)

Comment: You need to provide more information. There are many ways to iterate over data in Python but without knowing what you're trying to do, no one can help.

Comment: what operation do you wanna do on top of every value in a list?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? There is no "magic" you can sprinkle on loops to make them faster. In Python, a for loop is as optimized as it gets. I'm not sure why you don't just do `for item in lst: ...` though. Don't loop over a `range`, that is almost never what you want

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to iterate over a list.

Using FOR loop:
Creating a list with values until 10

```
a = list(range(10))
a
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Iterating the values using a FOR loop

```
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

**Output:**

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways

### List comprehension

```
lst = range(1000)
result = [do_stuff(i) for i in lst]
incriminated = [i+1 for i in lst]  # example of adding 1 to all elements
```

### `map`

```
lst = range(1000)
result = list(map(do_stuff,lst))
incriminated = list(map(lambda x: x+1,lst))  # example of adding 1 to all elements
```

### foreach loop

```
lst = range(1000)
for i in lst:
    do_stuff(i)
```

foreach loop is generally slower